# Chrome Extension:How to change a specific website's style?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to change a specific website's style with chrome extension but it is not working.

What do i need to do to make this extension works?

My **manifest.json** is;

```
 {
  "name": "Black Youtube",
  "description": "Make Youtube Black!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
       "js":["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}`
```

and my **style.css** is;

```
    body {
    background:black !important;
}
```

Comment: it must be: background-color

Comment: Dude tried but not working @AntonHarald

Comment: But if i do it , i get error @AntonHarald

Comment: sorry, my advices regarding the match pattern where not correct. I got it working now, see the answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [manual](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for more details about match-patterns in chrome-extensions.

The following however matches all youtube.com pages, and subpages (also in sub domains), weather via http or https.

```
"*://*.youtube.com/*"
```